# A network related or instance specific error only in my machine

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting the below error when I try to connect to SQL server from C# code

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

My connection String looks like this

> "Data Source={DatabaseServer};Initial
>   Catalog={DatabaseName};Integrated Security=SSPI;Enlist=false;"

I have tried all the option which I found in lots of articles but could not solve the issue. One more thing to note is my colleague is able to run the same code from his machine. So it is obviously not problem with SQL server. It has to do something with my machine.can anyone give me any pointers what could be the problem? I am able to connect to SQL server instance through SSMS.

Comment: Sounds like your machine can't see the server on the network. It could be a whole laundry list of possibilities.

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if the machine is reachable from your pc using ping/traceroute?

Comment: @gmiley Yes did ping and I can see the reply

Comment: Double check the connection string (debug your code) probably you point to the wrong server...

Comment: @Max no, Connection string is correct as I mentioned the same code with same connection string works on my colleague machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out...Actually I am working on a remote machine and I created a new project in visual studio which gets created in remote drive by default. so it does not seems to find instance from remote drive but it works when I copy it to my local drive..

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect to your SQL server through SSMS and the error message looks like the connection string is wrong (or only working for some people somehow), you could compare the parameters SSMS uses in the connection dialog to those in your connection string in the C# code.

If you find any differences there, they could be the error you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is the provider in your connection string? Something like
Data Source=SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;